# Get and manipulate phone contacts by ngCordova in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to get all phone contacts by [$cordovaContacts](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/) and manipulate them to send for server. like this

```
$scope.contacts = [];

$cordovaContacts.find({
      filter: '', 
      fields: ['displayName','phoneNumbers']
}).then(function (allContacts) {

    angular.forEach(allContacts, function (contact, index) {
          $scope.contacts.push({
              "first_name": contact.name.givenName,
              "last_name": contact.name.familyName,
              "phone_number": contact.phoneNumbers[0].value
          });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p style="white-space: pre;">{{contacts | json: 3}}</p>
```

But `angular.forEach` not working and there is No error, whats wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `allContacts` is not null?

Comment: Yes, because when I use `$scope.contacts = allContacts`, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally solve the problem ::**

```
$cordovaContacts.find({
      filter: '', 
      fields: ['displayName', 'name', 'phoneNumbers']
}).then(function (allContacts) {

    var contacts = [];

    angular.forEach(allContacts, function (contact, index) {

       if (contact.phoneNumbers != null && 
           contact.phoneNumbers[0].type == 'mobile' &&
           contact.name != null) {

           // if user have firstName and lastName
           if (contact.name.givenName && contact.name.familyName) {

             contacts.push({
                "first_name": contact.name.givenName,
                "last_name": contact.name.familyName,
                "phone_number": contact.phoneNumbers[0].value
             });

           } else {

             contacts.push({
                "first_name": contact.name.givenName ? contact.name.givenName : '',
                "last_name": contact.name.familyName ? contact.name.familyName : '',
                "phone_number": contact.phoneNumbers[0].value
             });

           }

        }

    });    

});
```